# Convert match statement to partial function when foreach is used

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, foreach, pattern-matching

IntelliJ gives me a hint on a following code:

```
val l = List(0, "1", 2, "3")

l.foreach{_ match {case xx:Int => println(xx);case _ =>}}
```

The hint is "Convert match statement to partial function"

When I change the foreach to

```
l.foreach{case x:Int => println(x)}
```

I get the `scala.MatchError` exception. I can use `collect` instead of `foreach`, however that produces a resulting `List` which is never used.

Is there some common way how to handle this (something like foreach ignoring the non-matched values), or should I just ignore the hint?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put default case back:

```
val l = List(0, "1", 2, "3")

l.foreach { case xx:Int => println(xx); case _ => }
```

IDEA will be happy:

[image]

In fact, that is what IDEA will generate if you tap proposed action (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when your caret points to yellowed text)