# scala: convert match statement to pattern matching anonymous function - with values

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

like similar question: [Convert match statement to partial function when foreach is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760272/convert-match-statement-to-partial-function-when-foreach-is-used).  Now similarly, IntelliJ asks me to improve my code.  The difference is, that I use values for the matching:

```
val matchMe = "Foo"
keys.foreach(key =>
  key match {
    case `matchMe` => somethingSpecial()
    case _ => somethingNormal(key, calcWith(key))
  })
```

Refactoring this to a anonymous pattern-matching function would look something like:

```
keys.foreach {
  case `matchMe` => somethingSpecial(_)
  case _ => somethingNormal(_, calcWith(_)) //this doesn't work
}
```

Note that in the second case, I cannot use `_` since I need it twice.  Is there some way to use an anonymous pattern-matching function here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't use the wildcard `_` here, its purpose is to indicate you don't care about the value you're matching against.

You can use a named parameter :

```
keys.foreach {
  case `matchMe` => somethingSpecial(matchMe)
  case nonSpecialKey => somethingNormal(nonSpecialKey, calcWith(nonSpecialKey))
}
```

Without any restrictions placed on it, it will match any value. Do note that the order of `case`s is important, as `case x => ...` match anything and will essentially shortcut other `case` statements.

---

As an aside, I don't think your `somethingSpecial(_)` does what you want/expect it to. It's only a short version of `x => somethingSpecial(x)`, not `somethingSpecial(matchMe)`.

Comment: `f(_)` is `x => f(x)`.  And `ks foreach { case _ => f(_) }` is not `ks foreach { case x => f(x) }`.